# JQuery Datatable textbox column hover

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I'm new to JQuery and datatables, I have a question about using textboxes in a Jquery UI datatable column. I have a column which has textboxes. When I hover over a row I want my textbox background and border to change. I have added the logic to add/remove the css class using JQuery, but it does not seem to work in a datatable.

```
$('tr').each(function () {
    $('this').hover(function () {
        $('#myText').addClass('hover');
    }, function () {
        $('#myText').removeClass('hover');
    });
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CMR5Y/100/)

Any ideas using JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont need jquery to do this just use css:

```
#example tr input:hover{
     background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sg2w648a/)

if you want a jquery solution use this

```
table = $('#example').dataTable({
        "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            $('td:eq(1)', nRow).hover(
                function() {  $(this).find("input").addClass("hover") } ,
                function() { $(this).find("input").removeClass("hover") }
            );
        }
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubfnrjsf/)

this will effect the entire row

```
table = $('#example').dataTable({
        "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            $(nRow).hover(
                function() {  $(this).find("input").addClass("hover") } ,
                function() { $(this).find("input").removeClass("hover") }
            );
        }
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7251v65/)

Comment: I want only the textbox background color and border to change.

Comment: Yep, that definitely works. thanks! But I was looking to use JQuery. Do you have an example using JQuery?

Comment: This only works when hovering over the textbox but not the entire row :(

Comment: yes ofc.... my script bind the hover event on the input field... if you need to fire the event on the entire row... i will edit my answer with the solution... you just need to change the event target

Answer (score 0):

The CSS3 is the most elegant solution but if you really wanna do it with jquery do it like this:

```
$('tr').each(function () {
    $(this).hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('hover');
    });
});
```

In this case you shouldn't set the this in ', because it hands over the scope, the class or object you're in.